# Xamarin: Try to run the Project. I'm new bee for xamarin and want to run my xamarin ios project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I want to run the xamarin ios project and maybe its native code for ios xamarin.
I install visual studio for mac and open the project, then add missing packages.
But in One package Zxing.Mobile I get the error (I can't find relative package) So I comment related code and try to run the project. So I get the few errors and here I attached that snap

[image]

So please help me I'm iOS native developer and want to run this xamarin project.

Comment: Just wondering, What have you tried so far? The code for the project might also make the question a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when a dependency of your nuget package is having an issue and can't be linked. You can try installing the dependency nuget package manually and that should resolve it.

Comment: right click on your solution and selecte "Manage Nuget Packages For Solution". Select browse at the top and enter the name of the nuget package you are looking for. select the package you want to install and then select the projects you want to install it to on the right.

Comment: from the error the framework that is missing is GoogleAppMeasurement. Uninstall Zxing.Mobile nuget package and see if you still get the error.